# Proving $\int_0^1 \ln(\sin(1)/ \sin(x) )dx \leq 1$ using elementary calculus

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, inequality, definite-integrals

Is there any hint how can I show:

$\int_0^1 \ln(\sin(1)/ \sin(x) )dx \leq 1$

I tried using $\ln x \leq x -1$, but it couldn't work.

Thanks.

Comment: Replace the integrand by three or four terms of its Taylor series (or series that can handle $\ln(0).$

Comment: Using $\ln(y)\leq y-1$ is too weak a bound.  If we look at the argument to $\ln$, it varies between $1$ (when $x=1$) and $\infty$ (when $x\rightarrow 0$).  So, you need a bound that has more control when the argument approaches $\infty$.

Answer (score 7):

Notice that
\begin{align}
x \sin(1) \le \sin x
\end{align}
for $x \in [0, 1]$. Then it follows that
\begin{align}
\int^1_0 \ln\left(\frac{\sin(1)}{\sin(x)} \right) dx \le \int^1_0 \ln\left(\frac{1}{x} \right)d x = 1. 
\end{align}

Answer (score -1):

Notice that
$$\ln\left(\frac{\sin(1)}{\sin(x)}\right) = \ln(\sin(1)) - \ln(\sin(x))$$
Whence

$$\int_0^1 \ln(\sin(1)) - \ln(\sin(x))\ \text{d}x = \ln(\sin(1)) - \int_0^1 \ln(\sin(x))\ \text{d}x$$

Now since the range of integration is $[0, 1]$ you might want to use Taylor Series for the sine. At the first order $\sin(x)\approx x + O(x^3)$ hence

$$-\int_0^1 \ln(\sin(x))\ \text{d}x \approx -\int_0^1 \ln(x)\ \text{d}x = -1$$

Altogether we have: $\ln(\sin(1)) + 1$ which is less than one since $\sin(1) \in [0, 1]$.

If you add more terms like $\sin(x) = x - \frac{x^3}{6} + O(x^5)$ then we have

$$-\int_0^1 \ln\left(x\left(1 - \frac{x^2}{6}\right)\right)\ \text{d}x = -\int_0^1 \ln(x) + \ln\left(1 - \frac{x^2}{6}\right)\ \text{d}x = -\left(1 - \left(x \log \left(1-\frac{x^2}{6}\right)-2 x+2 \sqrt{6} \tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{6}}\right)\right)\right)_0^1 = 3+\log \left(\frac{6}{5}\right)-2 \sqrt{6} \coth ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{6}\right)$$

By similar considerations We can see that number is slightly greater than one, but adding the term $\ln(\sin(1))$ we obtain a number less than $1$.

This is rather a numerical proof, not an analytical one. Also because the more terms you add, the more complicated the integral might become. But since we are approximating terms in a good range, this also will work with more terms, and more generally it will work with the whole series.